# Expression douteuse sans rapport bien établi avec le texte

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, adjectifs

Dans un texte de Schopenhauer on trouve une expression qui est pour moi inexplicable : "*si bien veau*". (ARTHUR SCHOPENHAUER, APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE)

> Néanmoins,
> quand une affection morbide du système nerveux ou
> de l'appareil digestif vient prêter la main à une
> δυσκολια innée, alors celle-ci peut atteindre ce haut
> degré où un malaise permanent produit le dégoût de
> la vie, d'où résulte le penchant au suicide. Celui-ci
> peut alors être provoqué par les plus minimes
> contrariétés; à un degré supérieur du mal, il n'est
> même plus besoin de motif, la seule permanence du
> malaise suffit pour y déterminer. Le suicide
> s'accomplit alors avec une réflexion si froide et une
> si inflexible résolution que le malade à ce stade,
> placé déjà d'ordinaire sous surveillance, l'esprit
> constamment fixé sur cette idée, profite du premier
> moment où la surveillance se sera relâchée pour
> recourir, sans hésitation, sans lutte et sans effroi, à
> ce moyen de soulagement pour lui si naturel en ce
> moment et si bien veau.

Il est apparent que « veau » est [l'adjectif (TLFi)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/veau).

> **1.** Personne paresseuse, sans énergie et souvent stupide. Un grand veau. Pourquoi fallait-il précisément ce gros veau plein de sale bière et d'alcool pour que ce miracle s'accomplît? (Sartre, Nausée, 1938, p. 221).
> − **Empl. adj**. Paresseux, nonchalant. Sur ce, bonsoir. − Dieu, que je suis veau! Je te laisse [à Flaubert] le titre de vache, que tu t'attribues dans tes jours de lassitude (Sand, Corresp., t. 5, 1867, p. 183).

Est-ce le moyen de soulagement qui serait si bien paresseux ? « Bien » ne semble pas convenir comme adverbe pour modifier « paresseux » ; cela serait-il dû à une mauvaise traduction de l'allemand « wohl » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il semble que ce soit une erreur de frappe ou de copie. En cherchant d'autres versions de ce passage, je suis tombé sur [ceci](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Schopenhauer_-_Aphorismes_sur_la_sagesse_dans_la_vie,_1880,_trad._Cantacuz%C3%A8ne.djvu/39) :

> [...] Celui-ci peut alors être provoqué par les plus minimes contrariétés ; à un degré supérieur du mal, il n’est même plus besoin de motif, la seule permanence du malaise suffit pour y déterminer. Le suicide s’accomplit alors avec une réflexion si froide et une si inflexible résolution que le malade à ce stade, placé déjà d’ordinaire sous surveillance, l’esprit constamment fixé sur cette idée, profite du premier moment où la surveillance se sera relâchée pour recourir, sans hésitation, sans lutte et sans effroi, à ce moyen de soulagement pour lui si naturel en ce moment et si bien **venu**.

Comment: *Adieu veau, vaches, cochons, couvée...*

Answer (score 2):

> cela serait-il dû à une mauvaise traduction de l'allemand « wohl » ?

Non, il s'agit d'une coquille. Schopenhauer écrit :

> …jenes ihm jetzt natürliche und **willkommene** Erleichterungsmittel

Il faut donc lire : « et si **bienvenu** ».